# Django: how can I cache a template fragment conditionally?

Tags: django

I currently cache a page for unauthenticated users like this:

```
{% with cache_timeout=request.user.is_authenticated|yesno:"0,600" %}
  {% cache cache_timeout my_page_cache user.is_authenticated LANGUAGE_CODE obj.pk obj.updated %}
    <p>This content is cached if the user is not authenticated</p>
  {% endcache %}
{% endwith %}
```

This works great, but now I want to change the condition of the `with` block to `request.user == obj.user`.

How can I rewrite that code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it purely inside template file(though it's not DRY):

```
   {% if request.user == obj.user %}
    {% with cache_timeout = 0 %}
     {% cache cache_timeout my_page_cache request.user|is_object_owner:obj LANGUAGE_CODE obj.pk obj.updated %}
        <p>This content is cached if the user is not authenticated</p>
      {% endcache %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% else %}
    {% with cache_timeout = 600 %}
     {% cache cache_timeout my_page_cache request.user|is_object_owner:obj LANGUAGE_CODE obj.pk obj.updated %}
        <p>This content is cached if the user is not authenticated</p>
      {% endcache %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: This is invalid template syntax on Django 1.11, but I made it work using a template tag (see my own answer). Thanks!

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using a template tag:

```
{% with cache_timeout=request.user|is_object_owner:obj|yesno:"0,600" %}
  {% cache cache_timeout my_page_cache request.user|is_object_owner:obj LANGUAGE_CODE obj.pk obj.updated %}
    <p>This content is cached if the user is not authenticated</p>
  {% endcache %}
{% endwith %}
```

```
@register.filter
def is_object_owner(user, obj):
    # type: (User, Object) -> bool
    return user == obj.user
```